# How can I install Windows 8 on a virtual disk with 10GB of space?

Tags: windows-8, virtual-machine

I am having trouble setting up Windows 8 on a virtual machine that has a limited hard drive capacity.

How can install Windows 8 on a 10GB HD?

There were some custom builds of Windows 7, that could do this, but I couldn't find the method they used to hack the limit. Does anybody know how to do this on Windows 8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Legos WinToolkit might do the trick for you. It says it supports Windows 8. This is a nice app but not super user friendly. By that I mean the flow of the process is not the way I would do it.

Answer (score 0):

Virtual drives use expanding size as needed. So when you initially specify the hard drive size of say 40gb, the actual physical size is almost nothing until you start to add files during the install. Windows 8 has a requirement of 16gb (32bit) or 20gb (64bit). So you won't be able to install windows unless the virtual drive promises that size virtual disk.
However, once loaded, windows 8 will be smaller than that. (I think its like 9gb?).
That should get you a bootable image. From there, you can attempt to delete some components/files and then re-compress the virtual drive to shrink it a bit more.